# system_cpu_usage is Nan when compiled in native

Tags: native, quarkus, micrometer

In my quarkus application i'm using micrometer to retrieve metrics (like in this guide : https://quarkus.io/guides/micrometer).
In JVM mode everything works fine, but in native mode system_cpu_usage is "Nan".
I tried bumping micrometer to 1.8.4 and adding :

```
{
  "name":"com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean", "allPublicMethods": true
},
```

to my reflect-config.json but no luck. I also tried generating the reflect-config (and other native configuration files) with the graalvm tracing agent but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bug.

Micrometer is looking for a few known implementations of the MXBean:

https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/b087856355667abf9bf2386265edef8642e0e077/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/binder/system/ProcessorMetrics.java#L55

```java
    private static final List<String> OPERATING_SYSTEM_BEAN_CLASS_NAMES = Arrays.asList(
        "com.ibm.lang.management.OperatingSystemMXBean", // J9
        "com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean" // HotSpot
    );
```

so that it can find the methods that it should be invoking...

https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/b087856355667abf9bf2386265edef8642e0e077/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/binder/system/ProcessorMetrics.java#L80

```
        this.operatingSystemBean = ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();
        this.operatingSystemBeanClass = getFirstClassFound(OPERATING_SYSTEM_BEAN_CLASS_NAMES);
        Method getCpuLoad = detectMethod("getCpuLoad");
        this.systemCpuUsage = getCpuLoad != null ? getCpuLoad : detectMethod("getSystemCpuLoad");
        this.processCpuUsage = detectMethod("getProcessCpuLoad");
```

(Note specifically "getFirstClassFound", which is constrained against the first list).

Speculation on my part, but I suspect Graal is returning a different type, which is possible from here:
https://github.com/oracle/graal/blob/6ba65dad76a4f54fa59e1ed2a62dedd3afe39928/substratevm/src/com.oracle.svm.core/src/com/oracle/svm/core/jdk/management/ManagementSupport.java#L166

would take some digging to know which, but I would open an issue with Micrometer so we can sort it out.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer, i just opened an issue on micrometer github : https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/issues/3121